# less than or equal to not working in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

i want to fetch all data from my table 'flock' where field name is  f_date
having  date and time. i want only date portion.   i try this

```
$this->db->where('f_date >=', $f_date)
$this->db->where('f_date <=', $t_date)
```

where `$f_date` is from date and `$t_date` is to date `$f_date` from date is working well but $t_date

fetch record one less than `$t_date`. e.g record present on `14-11-2016` is fetched when `$t_date` is post as `15-11-2016`

Comment: u just need to change the order, and look your date values..

Comment: You need the dates to be in the format `yyyy-mm-dd` i.e. a format that MYSQL expects dates to be entered as

Comment: Can you provide us a clean example?

Comment: what are the values of `$f_date` and `$t_date`?

Comment: -@RiggsFolly date format is not problem because i am getting desired result between two dates but $t_date select one less than the selected $t_date

Comment: format is not problem because i am getting both dates that is from date and to date but it select to date only if one day is added to the search

Answer (score 0):

You can use BETWEEN to get the result.

```
$this->db->where("f_date BETWEEN $f_date AND $t_date");
```

Comment: can you please specify Database, as it works fine on MySQL database if you are using date format as "YYYY-MM-DD"

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.It works for me

```
public function getData() {

        $query = "SELECT * FROM `flock` WHERE cast(f_date as date) >= DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE('$f_date', '%d-%m-%Y'), '%Y-%m-%d')  AND cast(f_date as date) <= DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE('$t_date', '%d-%m-%Y'), '%Y-%m-%d')";

        $result = $this->db->query($query);

        return $result->result_array();
    }
```